# Xamarin - Switch statement for Follow and unFollow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin, xamarin.android, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a follow and unfollow techniques to user profile
I made this code but the main problem is that the user followed successfully but if you tap the button again the toast will show that unfollowed and the button image will change (like you will follow again) but if you refresh the following image show again it's like nothing happen

```
switch (BtnFollow?.Tag?.ToString())
                {
                    case "Add": //Sent follow 
                        BtnFollow.SetColor(Color.ParseColor(AppSettings.MainColor));
                        BtnFollow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_tick);
                        BtnFollow.Tag = "friends";
                        DataUser.IsFollowing = true;

                        Toast.MakeText(Context, Context.GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_Sent_successfully_followed),
                            ToastLength.Short)?.Show();
                        PollyController.RunRetryPolicyFunction(new List<Func<Task>> { () => RequestsAsync.User.FollowUnFollowUserAsync(UserId, true) });
                        break;
                    case "friends": //Sent un follow 
                        BtnFollow.SetColor(Color.ParseColor("#444444"));
                        BtnFollow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_add);
                        BtnFollow.Tag = "Add";
                        DataUser.IsFollowing = false;

                        Toast.MakeText(Context, Context.GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_Sent_successfully_Unfollowed),
                            ToastLength.Short)?.Show();
                        PollyController.RunRetryPolicyFunction(new List<Func<Task>> { () => RequestsAsync.User.FollowUnFollowUserAsync(UserId, false) });
                        break;
                }

                var dataUser = GlobalContext?.MainFragment?.ArtistsAdapter?.ArtistsList?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == DataUser.Id);
                if (dataUser != null)
                {
                    dataUser.IsFollowing = DataUser.IsFollowing;
                    GlobalContext.MainFragment.ArtistsAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Methods.DisplayReportResultTrack(exception);
            }
        }
```

and this code to check the following status

```
if (DataUser.IsFollowing != null && DataUser.IsFollowing.Value) // My Friend
                {
                    BtnFollow.SetColor(Color.ParseColor(AppSettings.MainColor));
                    BtnFollow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_tick);
                    BtnFollow.Tag = "friends";
                }
                else  //Not Friend
                {
                    BtnFollow.SetColor(Color.ParseColor("#444444"));
                    BtnFollow.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_add);
                    BtnFollow.Tag = "Add";
                }
            }
```

Comment: you are using a UI property ("Tag") to track a state variable.  This is not a good strategy.  You already had a bool property on your model, `IsFollowing` that you should be using instead.

Comment: I tried to remove Tag, can you explain more how to use IsFollowing instead? @Jason

Comment: This link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) may help you.